# PHP Session Cookie unset on IOS Safari force-close?

Tags: php, ios, session, cookies, safari

When I set my PHP Session cookie with the below syntax:

```
setcookie('rememberme', $cookie, time()+7500, '/');
```

It works just fine in the browsers I tested (Chrome and Firefox), but when I login to my site on IOS Safari, then double tap my home button and swipe up on the app, then go back into safari I am automatically logged out and the cookie is unset. Is there anyway to prevent this? I have already tried changing the cookie lifetime and gc_maxlifetime in the php.ini file with no success.